# How to scroll in a nav element using seleniumbase in python

Tags: python, html, scroll, seleniumbase

```html
<nav class="flex h-full w-full flex-col p-2 gizmo:px-3 gizmo:pb-3.5 gizmo:pt-0" aria-label="Menu">
```

This is the nav although, its a-lot longer its full of divs

I just want to know how to scroll till the end of the menu.
Edit:
loading element that has to be accounted for

```html
<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="animate-spin text-center" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

and under it there are many line elements

top of nav xpath:

```html
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/nav
```

top of svg xpath:

```html
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/nav/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/svg
```

do you need scrollbar html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of specialized scroll methods in [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase):

```py
self.scroll_to(selector)
self.slow_scroll_to(selector)
self.scroll_into_view(selector)
self.scroll_to_top()
self.scroll_to_bottom()
```

But you might not even need to scroll to the element. There's a `self.js_click(selector)` method, which lets you click on hidden elements that exist in the HTML.

Here's an example test that uses that method to click a hidden logout menu item from the nav:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class SwagLabsLoginTests(BaseCase):
    def login_to_swag_labs(self):
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        self.wait_for_element("div.login_logo")
        self.type("#user-name", "standard_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        self.click('input[type="submit"]')

    def test_swag_labs_login(self):
        self.login_to_swag_labs()
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_element('.inventory_item:contains("Backpack")')
        self.js_click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("div#login_button_container")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [scroll to element](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/#scroll-to-element) functionality? As you are saying there are divs in nav. you can try to scroll to those divs